# How can I combine the google custom search with my all ready defined search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-search-api, search-box

What I am trying to achieve is to combine my already existing search with the google custom search. 
I have this form action:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="#">
                <p><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type an artist name..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control btn btn-primary w100"></p>
            </form>
            <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
```

And I want to somehow use JQuery to be able click search bar and it will instead look into the google custom search:

```
 <div>
        <script>
          (function() {
            var cx = 'myID';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
          })();
        </script>
        <gcse:search></gcse:search>
    </div >
```

Like so far I think to start it, I will do this:

```
 $("form").on("submit", function() {...
```

So Now I am wondering if I can manipulate the google custom search, that way I won't have multiple search boxes, and just one functional search box, where I can input a search then I can perhaps have the YouTube search API display that video, and at same time the google custom search will output the result of that input.
As of now, I have two search boxes doing two different things, but my end goal is to combine them and then I can just click on one search bar, instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this possible is using ajax to submit your form and "inject" google's results with your own results on top or in between each elements.